# How can I create a DataFrame with Results from a comparison Matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to transform a comparison matrix into a DataFrame listing all combinations and the results from the comparison matrix.

This is how it looks so far:

```
import pandas as pd

x1 = ["x11","x12"]
x2 = ["x21","x22"]
y1 = ["y11","y12"]
y2 = ["y21","y22"]

matrix = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns = [x1, x2], index = [y1,y2])

print(matrix)

[Out:]         
        x11 x12
        x21 x22
y11 y21   1   2
y12 y22   3   4
```

Now I want to create a DataFrame which enlists all combinations of index-pairs and their result.

The Output Dataframe should look like this

```
x11 x21 y11 y21 1
x12 x22 y11 y21 2
x11 x21 y12 y22 3
x12 x22 y12 y22 4
```

I've tried multiple ways of putting column-names and indexes into lists and then adding them together. But nothing worked so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please also excuse my inexperience with posting questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
out = matrix.stack([0,1])
print (out)
y11  y21  x11  x21    1.0
          x12  x22    2.0
y12  y22  x11  x21    3.0
          x12  x22    4.0
dtype: float64
```

If order of levels is important add [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html):

```
out = matrix.stack([0,1]).reorder_levels([2,3,0,1])
print (out)
x11  x21  y11  y21    1.0
x12  x22  y11  y21    2.0
x11  x21  y12  y22    3.0
x12  x22  y12  y22    4.0
dtype: float64
```